# Using getpass() fails in the self.__init__() method but works fine when used functionally. Why is this?

Tags: python, class, oop, initialization, getpass

I can't work out what I'm doing wrong here. I want to set up a new user if this class is instantiated and there is no user already pickled. My `__init__` method currently looks like this:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if os.path.isfile(f"{get_cwd()}/user.pickle"):
            self.load_user()
        else:
            self.email_address = input("What's your email address?: ")
            self.email_password = base64.b64encode(getpass("What's your email password?: ").encode("utf-8"))
            self.save_user()
```

However, when I instantiate the class, it doesn't get past asking for self.email_address. If I change the self.email_password to a simple input function it works. What am I doing wrong with using `getpass()` here?

I've tried making a separate function to receive / encode the password variable and calling that from within the `__init__` method but it does the same thing.

If I make the whole script functional if works (but it's a little lengthy!)

Why am I having problems with `getpass` and a class-based approach??

**EDIT**: was trying to run through PyCharm terminal and the above is more or less irrelevant.

Comment: `getpass` depends on the environment it's using. How are you running this code? Are you using PyCharm? Does running it in a terminal make a difference?

Comment: damn! I even knew that already! yes, that is the issue. I don't even need to test it, I've had the same problem before lol! thank you! I will remember this now!

Comment: You can edit the run configuration and tick "Emulate terminal in output console" to fix it in pycharm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @Alex Hall for reminding me that `getpass` doesn't work through the PyCharm terminal. Works perfectly fine in a normal terminal.